# Linux: Running a specific command as root

Tags: root, sudo

I need to run a command as "some_user" without being asked for the password, so I type:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Adding this line *does* work:

```
some_user ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But adding this line (with only the specific command "whitelisted") does *not* work:

```
some_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/"some_service start"

$ sudo /etc/init.d/"some_service start"
```

...will still ask for the password.
 What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT:* Corrected (but this still asks for password)

```
some_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/"some_service start"

$ sudo /etc/init.d/some_service start
```

Comment: Why the quotes? I suspect there is no file named `some_service\ start` in `/etc/init.d`. You are confusing `sudo` by trying to make the argument part of the command name...

Comment: @twalberg - yes, correct, there was a pair of quotes that didn't belong there: I have corrected it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Looks to me like the quotes are still in your `sudoers` file... But maybe that's just a mis-post...

Comment: @twalberg - Sorry, I didn't really think through/understand what you were saying... It works now without the 2nd pair of quotes, so: Thanks! (Also: I'll accept your answer, if you let me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes, both on the command line and in the `sudoers` file. The quotes make `sudo` and the shell think that there should be a file in `/etc/init.d` named "`some_service start`", rather than seeing `start` as an argument to `/etc/init.d/some_service`.